# How to prove p(C|A) = p(C|B) * p(B|A)?

Tags: probability, self-study

A, B, C are events in a sequence.
How to prove p(C|A) = p(C|B) * p(B|A)?
Do I need to assume something first?

Thanks.

Comment: What if C and A occur, but B does not occur? Think it through.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: What is definition of the sets A, B and C?  What makes you think such an equality would hold?

Comment: In response to your edit, what does  "A, B, C are events in a sequence" mean? Is there any way for C to occur if B doesn't occur?

Answer (score 2):

Just take the following example:

- A: event that it is winter.
- B: event that it is January.
- C: event that it is February.

Now, $P(C|A) \ne 0$ and $P(B|A) \ne 0$ but $P(C|B) = 0$

Comment: It appears you do not live near the Equator nor in the southern hemisphere!

Comment: Following up on @whuber , there is a Clintonesque matter of it depends on what the meaning of it is is.. It could be January in U.S.A while it is February in Europe.  Anyhow, sort of kidding - I upvoted.